# data dictionary to html table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following data dictionary, I would like to convert this to HTML table - tried different things but no success.

```
data =  {'102 Not Out': "('75', '04 May 2018'),N/A",'2.0': "('84', 'Expected in January 2019'),8.5",'3 Dev': "('0', '11 May 2018'),No IMDB Info Available",'Adityam': "('34', '27 April 2018'),No IMDB Info Available"}
```

Here is the what I have so far

```
message ='<table><tr><th>Movies</th><th>Release Date</th><th>Rating</th><th>IMDB Rating</th></tr>'
message += '<tr><td>' + '</td><td>'.join(data.keys()) + '</td></tr>'
message += '</table>'
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
| Movies      | Release Date             | Rating | IMDB Rating            |  |
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
| 102 Not Out | 04 May 2018              | 75     | N/A                    |  |
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
| 2.0         | Expected in January 2019 | 84     | 8.5                    |  |
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
| 3 Dev       | 11 May 2018              | 0      | No IMDB Info Available |  |
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
| Adityam     | 27 April 2018            | 34     | No IMDB Info Available |  |
+-------------+--------------------------+--------+------------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 3 - `literal_eval()` and `.items()`

Your value contains a `tuple` and a `str`. So you need to split it.

So should be like:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for key, value in data.items():
   message += '<tr>'
   values = value.split(',')
   t = literal_eval(','.join(values[:2])) # tuple
   message += """
      <td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td><td>{}</td>
   """.format(key, t[0], t[1], values[2])
   message += '</tr>'
```

#### Output

```
102 Not Out 75  04 May 2018                 N/A
2.0         84  Expected in January 2019    8.5
3 Dev       0   11 May 2018                 No IMDB Info Available
Adityam     34  27 April 2018               No IMDB Info Available
```

Comment: Is there a way to address the sort in the date column?

Comment: there is but it's not straight forward for you have strings like `Expected in`

Comment: I tried using OrderedDict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda t: t[1])) but not what I am looking for ... any suggestion?

Comment: for `t1` is not a straight forward date format. you can extract the "string Date", convert it to a `Date` object then sort.